# Generate Chaotic Time Series using CellularAutomaton[]

Tags: time-series, cellular-automata

If possible, How could I generate a chaotic Time series using `CellularAutomaton[]`.

I am especially interested in Rule 30.

A friend told me it was possible but I have yet not found the way to do so.

Comment: I find several of us asking you this every single time... [did you read the documentation](http://wolfram.com/xid/0d6e8l44ia-fgx)?

Comment: @R.M.I am sorry but i think several of you are overestimating how intuitive Mathematica help menu is. To me, It is at best only when you want to see some properties or options. Not when you are looking for something new. Now I also ask this question thinking it is good keywords for this site. I do look for information before asking. I spent 5 min looking around, unsuccessfully. Please let me know what should be my rules before asking. i`ll be happy to comply if you think it is in the interest of Mathematica and its forum.

Comment: We all fully understand how intimidating Mathematica's documentation can be at first, and we certainly don't think that such questions are bad or unacceptable... they're perfectly fine questions for this site! We just feel that _you_ (given the length of time you've been on SO and here) ought to spend a bit more than 5 mins on the documentation :) In any case, don't take it the wrong way — we certainly need questions to grow the site, but not questions for the sake of keywords :)

Comment: @R.M. Echo ;-).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a line right out of the help for `CellularAutomaton`.

```
ListLinePlot[Accumulate[(-1)^CellularAutomaton[30, 
  {{1}, 0}, {500, {{0}}}]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]